# Android NotePad Tutorial 1 : Crash when I click on "Menu"

Tags: android

I am a beginner with Android, and I have a strange bug with the `NotePad Tutorial` (Exercice 1).
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

I imported the sources and completed the code, but when I run the app, and click on the "Menu" button, it crashes (The application .... has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.)

Then, I imported the solution, and it works normally.

I copied the whole code, resources, manifest from the solution to the first Project ... and still, everything is good with the first project, but when I click "Menu", I have the same crash.

Can someone explain where am I making a mistake?

After some researches, I opened the LogCat.
Here are the lines that seems interesting :

```
Displayed activity com.android.demo.notepad1/.Notepadv1: 1261 ms (total 1261 ms)
No keyboard for id 0

Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

getEntry failing because entryIndex 2 is beyond type entryCount 2

Failure getting entry for 0x7f040002 (t=3 e=2) in package 0: 0x80000001

Shutting down VM

threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)

Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f040002
```

I noted that `0x7f040002` refers to the `"menu_insert"` string in `R.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only guess is that R.java is not refreshed properly. Did you try a project>clean in Eclipse? That will recreate the R.java file.

Comment: Also make sure your res/values/strings.xml has the line: <string name="menu_insert">Add Item</string>

Comment: I first tried to change the "R.layout.menu_insert" to a hardcoded "Add Item" and it worked.

Then I tried what you said, Cleaning the project, and with the R.layout.menu_insert, it works ! So thanks, after cleaning, there is no more issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like the answer you linked to either.  After some research I added these two lines to my code. The editText name is from my own program:

```
         txtUserWord.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
         txtUserWord.setFocusable(true);
```

The error message in the logcat doesn't appear anymore.

Answer (score 0):

My issue for this (well actually the crash occurred after I pressed "Add Item") was a misspelling of the xmlns attribute.